# Why is Wolfram's (presumably more precise) Maclaurin series a much worse approximation than my own (presumably less precise) series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, wolfram-alpha, implicit-function

I recently answered [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4293809/815585) question, concerning the existence and nature of the implicit function defined by:

$$F(x,y)=x^3-y^3-3xy+1$$

For $x$ close to $0$ - roughly the range $|x|\lt0.4$ - I showed how to obtain a fourth-order Taylor approximation of the function $\phi(x)$ implicitly defined such that $\phi(0)=1,\,F(x,\phi(x))=0$ for all $x$ near $0$. Today in school, during free time, I went through the horrendously tedious process (just because I really did have nothing better to do!) of deriving a $10$th order Maclaurin approximation.

My formula is this:

$$\phi(x)\approx1-x+\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^4-\frac{10}{9}x^6-\frac{14}{9}x^7+\frac{274}{81}x^9+\frac{3118}{567}x^{10}$$

But WolframAlpha, which has the privilege of knowing the cubic formula, analytically solved for $x$ and gave the $10$th order Maclaurin expansion:

$$\phi(x)\approx1-x+\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^4-\frac{10}{9}x^6-\frac{14}{9}x^7+\frac{274}{81}x^9+\frac{418}{81}x^{10}$$

I was pleased to find that my calculations had been correct up until the $10$th term; the numerical discrepancy in the $x^{10}$ coefficient is $\approx0.339$, which I suppose is significant in the range of small $x$, but the purpose of my question is this:

When I plot the approximation given by Wolfram, I find it is **massively** less accurate than my approximation, even though one should be able to assume Wolfram knows how to take $10$th derivatives more accurately than I do... What are the possible reasons for a more accurate (in terms of coefficients) Maclaurin series being significantly less accurate (in terms of the error $|F(x,\varphi(x))-0|$ where $\varphi$ is the truncated series)?

The graph I reference is [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vwgysefmag) - ignore the irrelevant functions at the bottom.

The orange line at the bottom is the error from my approximation; the black line at the bottom is the error from Wolfram's approximation. You'll notice that the orange line is always relatively much closer to $0$ - how could this be the case? Surely Wolfram did not err?

Comment: I'd guess you made some kind of error in calculating the $10$th term, and it doesn't surprise me that you get something more accurate. Remember, Taylor polynomials are not tailored (sorry, not sorry) to get the least possible error! They are simply the unique polynomial that matches the first few derivatives of a given function at a given point. Indeed, Taylor polynomials need not even converge at all to the given function!

Comment: In my experience of “nice” functions however, getting the Taylor series correct and adding more terms always brings considerable accuracy benefit; nice functions have bounded and small remainders by the various remainder theorems, so I am baffled that even the 12th order approximation which wolfram gives, but I haven’t the time to derive for myself (yet), is worse than my (bad) 10th order one. @TheoBendit

Comment: Indeed, for "nice" (read: analytic) functions (which this function doubtlessly is), the Taylor series will successfully approximate the function on some non-trivial interval. But this is very different from claiming that you get the best possible approximation by polynomials when using Taylor polynomials. As a method for approximating functions, Taylor polynomials are conceptually simple and easy to implement, but in practice, they will often converge too slowly to be of practical use.

Comment: If all the resources one has are the nth derivatives of a function, and one value, do you know of a way to assemble these into a better approximation? The only other approximation techniques I have heard of like this are Puiseux series or Padé approximants, but it’s unclear to me how I could apply them here. Thanks for the advice anyway @TheoBendit

Comment: Fourier series are, in some ways, much nicer. Whenever you truncate a Fourier series, you are guaranteed to find the absolute **best** approximation of the given function with respect to the basis functions used (typically, some functions of the form $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$), with respect to the $L^2$ norm. While the best approximation with respect to an abstract norm may not be of any concrete benefit, it suggests that Fourier series, in some sense, approximate efficiently, unlike Taylor series.

Comment: I'm not an expert in practically approximating functions, sorry @FShrike. I don't know any way to tinker with Taylor series predictably to get better results. You could always manually play with the coefficients and see if you can reduce the error!

Comment: Oh really? @TheoBendit I have done a bit of study of Fourier series and have never come across this theorem; has it a name? Moreover, I note you said “typically”... Fourier series always use the trigonometric basis or the complex exponential as far as I know: are there others?

Comment: Indeed yes. They are sometimes known as "generalised Fourier series", where the variations on the complex exponential are replaced by a different orthonormal basis for the space. You could, for example, perform Fourier series with Chebyshev polynomials instead. As for a name for this result, I can't recall. I wanted to say "Parseval's theorem" or "Plancherel theorem", but these are not quite what I want. It is a standard result in the theory of Hilbert spaces and orthonormal bases, and essentially just boils down to Pythagoras's theorem.

Comment: I got gp-pari to expand Cardano's,  correct is 1 - x + 2/3*x^3 + 2/3*x^4 - 10/9*x^6 - 14/9*x^7 + 274/81*x^9 + 418/81*x^10 - 3058/243*x^12 - 4862/243*x^13 + O(x^14), where this CAS writes a rational coefficient before each x^n; kind of annoying. There are built-in difficulties, bifurcations; we can see that the coefficients are growing in absolute value

Comment: FS, one simple approach is to fix a polynomial degree  and an interval for $x$  of interest. Call the implicit function $f(x)$   anfd the polynomial $p(x).$   Then, for example, integrate $(f(x) - p(x))^2$  over your integral, then  minimize that integral by adjusting the coefficients.

Comment: @WillJagy. Did you notice that, in absolute value, the non-zero coefficients grow faster  than $e^{n/2}$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  no, that is interesting; I see it in your answer.

Comment: Still better for you ! Have a look at the addendum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of the differential equation $$\tag{1}x^2=\phi^2(x)\cdot\phi'(x)+\phi(x)+x\cdot\phi'(x) \quad \text{with} \quad \phi(0)=1$$ is
$$\phi(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+\sqrt{x^6+6 x^3+1}+1}}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}
   x}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+\sqrt{x^6+6 x^3+1}+1}}$$ Expanded as a series around $x=0$
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,x^n$$ the coefficients form the sequence
$$\left\{1,-1,0,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},0,-\frac{10}{9},-\frac{14}{9},0,\frac{274}{81
   },\frac{418}{81},0,-\frac{3058}{243},-\frac{4862}{243},0,\frac{37886}{729},\frac
   {61742}{729},0,-\frac{1502290}{6561}\right\}$$ which are the same as those given by @Will Jagy in comments.

Using the above expansion to $O\left(x^{19}\right)$, it is extremely good for $|x|\leq \frac 12$ and, over that range, the norm
$$\Phi=\int_{-\frac 12}^{\frac 12} \Big[\phi(x)-\text{series}\Big]^2 \,dx=3.96 \times 10^{-9}$$

If we compute the norm
$$\Phi_n=\int_{-\frac 12}^{\frac 12} \Big[\phi(x)-\text{series}_n\Big]^2 \,dx$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \log_{10}(\Phi_n) \\
 1,2 & -3.00952 \\
  3  & -4.00751 \\
 4,5 & -4.66992 \\
 6   & -5.41389 \\
 7,8 & -5.70164 \\
 9   & -6.38166 \\
 10,11 & -6.50545 \\
 12 & -7.15209 \\
 13,14 & -7.18720 \\
 15 & -7.81232 \\
 16,17 & -7.79253 \\
 18 & -8.40241 \\
 19,20 & -8.34550 \\
 21 & -8.94398 \\
 22,23 & -8.86038 \\
 24 & -9.45000 \\
 25,26 & -9.34632 \\
 27 & -9.92883 \\
 28,29 & -9.80953 \\
  30 & -10.3862
\end{array}
\right)$$
there is a very strong impact of $n$ on the result.

**Edit**

Looking at the absolute value of the non-zero coefficients $a_n$, they grow exponentially (faster than $e^{\frac n 2}$).

If we compute

$$F(x,\phi(x))=x^3-\phi(x)^3-3x\phi(x)+1$$ Wolfram Alpha expansion gives
$$F(x,\phi(x))=-\frac{3058 }{81}x^{12}+O\left(x^{13}\right)$$ while your gives
$$F(x,\phi(x))=-\frac{64 }{63}x^{10}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ and I agree with you that for $|x|\leq \frac 12$
$$\frac{3058 }{81}x^{12} \geq \frac{64 }{63}x^{10} \quad \text{if}\quad |x| \geq \sqrt{\frac{288}{10703}}=0.164$$

**Addendum**

Not considering them as Taylor series, let
$$\phi_1(x)=1-x+\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^4-\frac{10}{9}x^6-\frac{14}{9}x^7+\frac{274}{81}x^9+\frac{418}{81}x^{10}$$
$$\phi_2(x)=1-x+\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^4-\frac{10}{9}x^6-\frac{14}{9}x^7+\frac{274}{81}x^9+\frac{3118}{567}x^{10}$$

$$F_i=x^3-\phi_i(x)^3-3x\phi_i(x)+1$$
$$F_1-F_2=\frac{64 }{63}x^{10}\, P_{20}(x)$$ and $P_{20}(x)$ does not show any real root. Since its leading coefficient is positive  $\Big[\frac{9135556}{321489}\Big]$, $F_1 \geq F_2 ~~\forall ~x$ and **you are right !**.

We could even play with
$$\phi_3(x)=1-x+\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^4-\frac{10}{9}x^6-\frac{14}{9}x^7+\frac{274}{81}x^9+\left(\frac{418}{81}+\epsilon\right)x^{10}$$
$$F_1-F_3=3x^{10}\,Q_{20}(x)\,\epsilon+3x^{20} \,R_{10}(x)\,\epsilon^2+x^{30}\, \epsilon^3$$ The two polynomials have positive leading coefficients and do not show any real root. So, if $\epsilon >0$, which is the case in your problem $(\epsilon=\frac{64}{189})$, $F_1 \geq F_3 ~~\forall ~x$

Comment: Thank you for all that research. Since there is a strong impact of $n$ on the result, how is a higher order correct approximation worse than mine? I realise that there’s no definite reason “why not”, but even so it strikes me as strange

Comment: @FShrike. I do not see any difference comparing the plots. For me, the errors are the same. Computing the same norm, WA series gives $3.12\times 10^{-7}$ and for your $3.90\times 10^{-7}$

Comment: @FShrike. I think that I clarified something which makes you right. Have a loog at my edit.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, that clearly shows how my approximation is better despite being a miscalculation

Comment: @FShrike. Amazing, isn't it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Excellent research:)